# How to get Ajax div contents?

Tags: ajax, vbscript

```
Dim objWshShell,IE,searchStr
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
  .Visible = true
  .Navigate "http://site"
  Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
.....
.....
End With
```

How to get contents for `<div id="ajax_div"></div>` because didn't show codes in page source.